# Application Generate UUID?

Tags: java, android, hash, hashmap, uuid

I guess i kind of need more understand of how a UUID actually works. Im working on an application and i want the app to generate a UUID the first time the user downloads and runs the app.  Is it possible to generate a new uuid each time a user downloads an app?

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html
and maybe if there is another site other than android developer where i can understand or see examples of sombody using a uuid, can sombody post? Thank You.

Comment: This [post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html) should answer your question.

Comment: OKAY so this post was super good, im going through the code, but im having trouble understanding where the file is actually writing the UUID.Is it being written in an "installation" folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code to generate UUID :

```
String android_id = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext()
            .getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    Log.i("System out", "android_id : " + android_id);

    final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    final String tmDevice, tmSerial, androidId;
    tmDevice = "" + tm.getDeviceId();
    Log.i("System out", "tmDevice : " + tmDevice);
    tmSerial = "" + tm.getSimSerialNumber();
    Log.i("System out", "tmSerial : " + tmSerial);
    androidId = ""
            + android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(
                    getContentResolver(),
                    android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(androidId.hashCode(), ((long) tmDevice
            .hashCode() << 32)
            | tmSerial.hashCode());
    String UUID = deviceUuid.toString();
    Log.i("System out", "UUID : " + UUID);
```

Comment: I would add check for null on tm as getSystemService may return null if request service does not exist on particular device.

Answer (score 13):

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
```

This should generate you a random UUID for you to use how ever you wish.

Comment: I wish I had this answer 3 years ago.  I got it now, Thanks.

Comment: Ha Ha i actually came to this thread because i was looking for the answer then found the `.randomUUID()` in the Android Developer Docs by chance and thought id post it here its more than likely something that appeared in more recent version of the SDK.

Comment: It will generate you a random UUID each time it is called its best to just call this once and store the value it returns.